# How to add image/icon to a chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have some charts with their respective categories and those categories have a representative icon, There is way to add an icon/image over the chart in title section or nearby?

I tried to use this code on the title definition but it didn't work, only works when adding images to top of chart on every column.

```
useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return '<img src="./img/statics.png"><img>';
            }
```

i tried to put the image code on the div but looks like the code gets overridden by highcharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below function after chart

```
 chart.setTitle({
        useHTML: true,
        text: '<img src="./img/statics.png"/>';
        });
```

See the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/tzb47fz1/) , I used a website's logo in title.

Comment: in the html or the javascript file?

Comment: In js file, just after your highchart function